# return an output with % format in R

Tags: r, function

```
library(scales)
traded_price<-10
market_price<-9
breakeven<-function(traded_price, market_price){
  percent<-label_percent(1-(traded_price/market_price))
  percent
}
```

output should then be 1-(10/9), which is a 10% percent to be breakeven, however, the return is as below:

```
> breakeven(10,9)
function (x) 
number(x, accuracy = accuracy, scale = scale, prefix = prefix, 
    suffix = suffix, big.mark = big.mark, decimal.mark = decimal.mark, 
    trim = trim, ...)
```

May I know what have I do wrong in writing this function? Thanks a lot.

Comment: it returns a function.  Also, this may need some default argument

Comment: The scales::label_percent is for graphical scales applied to ggplot2 charts. Try `scales::percent()` instead

Comment: Or do `label_percent()(1 - traded_price / market_price)`.

Comment: This works: `breakeven <- function(traded_price, market_price){prcnt <- scales::label_percent()(1 - (traded_price / market_price)); prcnt}` - if you do `breakeven(10, 9)` it returns: `# [1] "-11%"`

Comment: @stefan, thanks the function works perfectly now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
breakeven <- function(traded_price, market_price){
  prcnt <- (1 - (traded_price / market_price))
  scales::percent(prcnt)
}

breakeven(10, 9)
#> [1] "-11%"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>